# grunt-contrib-less cannot find source files even though path is correct

Tags: javascript, css, compilation, less, gruntjs

I'm trying to get grunt-contrib-less to compile a less file for me. I have the following gruntfile:

```
less: {
        files: {
            "httpdocs/static/assets/css/result.css": "httpdocs/static/assets/css/dashboard.less"
        }
    },
```

The paths are definitely correct, I've triple checked that those files exist, yet, when I run grunt I get the following message:

```
Running "less:files" (less) task
>> Destination not written because no source files were provided.
```

What am I missing from my gruntfile to make it properly compile the less file? I'm tearing my hair out because I know it's probably something really simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did the answer below fix the problem for you?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `less` configuration isn't working because you need to put it into a specific `target` within `less`.  For example

```
less: {
   yourTarget : {
        files: {
            "httpdocs/static/assets/css/result.css": "httpdocs/static/assets/css/dashboard.less"
        }
   }
},
```

and run using

`grunt less:yourTarget`

You can name the `target` what ever you want but because `less` is a multi-task, it needs to have at least one target.

[Docs on configuring tasks with targets.](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets)

Comment: this was actually my problem as well!