# grunt-contrib-less not working (no errors but no output css)

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

I have a less compile grunt task where relative path to less files from grunt installed folder is `raw/less/source_map/`

here is the grunt file.

Gruntfile: (**EDIT**: changed to @Yogesh Khatri's code still same issue)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            files: { "raw/less/source_map/style.css" : "raw/less/source_map/style.less" }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['raw/less/source_map/style.less'],
                    tasks: ['default'],
                }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
};
```

on running it the command line displays

```
^CMacPro:grunt sagiavinashvarma$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "raw/less/source_map/style.less" changed.
Running "less:files" (less) task

Done, without errors.
Completed in 1.862s at Tue Dec 09 2014 15:03:37 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
```

but there is no style.css output. I have written the simplest grunt task without any options.
can anyone point out whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** 
I got the problem. It isn't working because less task need a specific target to work.
Try to change the code like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
          development: {
            files: { "raw/less/source_map/style.css" : "raw/less/source_map/style.less" }
          }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['raw/less/source_map/style.less'],
                    tasks: ['default'],
                }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
};
```

I got the error by running `grunt --verbose` which shows lot more information about the tasks. It gave me the output like

```
Verifying property less.files exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: report="min", banner=""
>> Destination not written because no source files were provided.
```

of which searching led me to this :- [grunt-contrib-less cannot find source files even though path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712214/grunt-contrib-less-cannot-find-source-files-even-though-path-is-correct)

Comment: my bad i changed the code. still no output. no errors